# Signature of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following matrix and I have to compute its signature :

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 &3&1 \\
3&0&-2\\
1&-2&0
\end{pmatrix}$$

I found $(2,1)$ but I don't know if it is correct. 
My attempt : 
I have to compute an orthogonal basis of $R^3$, so i need a vector $v_1 \in R^3$ such that $\beta(v_1,v_1)\neq 0$, where $\beta$ is the bilinear form related to $A$ ($A$ is its gram matrix is the canonical basis of $R^3$). I take $v_1=(1,1,1)^t$ and $\beta(v_1,v_1)=4\neq 0$. So, we have that $$R^2=Rv_1\oplus (Rv_1)^{\bot}$$
By following this processus, I find the following orthogonal basis of $R^3$ :

$$\{(1,1,1)^t,(1,-3,1)^t,(10,-19,21)^t\}$$
And i deduce that the signature is $(2,1)$, I am correct ? Any help would be appreciate,

Comment: You don’t really need an orthogonal basis. There are other diagonalizations that will give you the signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, two positive and one negative eigenvalues

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 3 & 1 \\ 
3 & 0 &  - 2 \\ 
1 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
6 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
6 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 3 & 1 \\ 
3 & 0 &  - 2 \\ 
1 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Algorithm discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 3 & 1 \\ 
3 & 0 &  - 2 \\ 
1 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 3 & 1 \\ 
3 & 0 &  - 2 \\ 
1 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
6 & 3 &  - 1 \\ 
3 & 0 &  - 2 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
6 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
 - 1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
6 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
6 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 3 & 1 \\ 
3 & 0 &  - 2 \\ 
1 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 2 }{ 3 }  \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
6 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
6 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 6 }  \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 3 & 1 \\ 
3 & 0 &  - 2 \\ 
1 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

---

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a simpler method: $\det A = -12$, so you have an odd number of negative eigenvalues; $\operatorname{tr}A=0$, so at least one eigenvalue must be positive. The only possibility is therefore two positive and one negative eigenvalue.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps too late but here is a comment about how to proceed in the general case:

The signature $(p,q)$ of a symmetric metric is given by $p=$ number of positive roots of the characteristic polynomial of the matrix, and $q=$ number of negative roots of the characteristic polynomial.

It is a computation to get that $c(x) = x^3 - 14 x +12$. By the Descartes rule of sings, the number of positive roots equals the number of changes of signs between the coefficients. Since the polynomial does not have $0$ as a root, then the signature must be $(2,1)$.